# Understanding dates a plotting with ggplot2 in R

Tags: r, date, csv, plot, ggplot2

I have a CSV file called *gdata.csv*, with data like:

```
id,date,totKm,eLiter,euros,liters,km
1,24-04-2010,23678,1.180,42.00,35.59,450
2,16-05-2010,24058,1.200,43.00,35.83,380
3,27-05-2010,24488,1.160,44.00,37.93,430
4,12-06-2010,24960,1.180,45.00,38.14,472
```

## With ggplot2

I just want to plot `date` and `eliter` in a **line char** with **ggplot2**, with this code:

```
x_date <- as.Date(gdata$date, format = "%d-%m-%Y")
ggplot(eliter, aes(x_date, eliter)) + geom_line()
```

But, it returns this error related with the class:
*Error: ggplot2 doesn't know how to deal with data of class numeric*

I have tried to make a `data.frame` but it stills returns the error:

```
d <- data.frame(xdate = x_date, yeliter=gdata$eLiter)
ggplot(d$xdate, aes(d$xdate, d$yeliter)) + geom_line()
```

*Error: ggplot2 doesn't know how to deal with data of class Date*

## With plot

I have managed to do this with plot() function:

```
plot(gdata$eLiter~as.Date(gdata$date, "%d-%m-%Y"), type = "s", xlab="Date",ylab="€/Liter", main="€/liter trend", col='blue')
```

And it works fine! But I can not do it with ggplot.

Could anyone help me?

Thank you very much.

Comment: After adding `x_date` to your data frame, still pass ggplot the entire data frame, that is `ggplot(d, aes(...))` not `ggplot(d$xdate, aes(...))`. The error message is telling you that you're passing ggplot a single vector of dates where it's expecting a full data frame.

Comment: Also, don't use `$` inside `aes()`. The point of ggplot having a `data` argument is that you don't keep re-typing the data frame. `ggplot(d, aes(x = xdate, y = yeliter)) + geom_line()`.

Comment: Ok @Gregor! Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

Add `+ scale_x_date()` like this:

```
Lines <- "id,date,totKm,eLiter,euros,liters,km
1,24-04-2010,23678,1.180,42.00,35.59,450
2,16-05-2010,24058,1.200,43.00,35.83,380
3,27-05-2010,24488,1.160,44.00,37.93,430
4,12-06-2010,24960,1.180,45.00,38.14,472"

DF <- read.csv(text = Lines)
DF$date <- as.Date(DF$date, "%d-%m-%Y")

library(ggplot2)
ggplot(DF, aes(date, eLiter)) +
  geom_line() +
  scale_x_date()
```

[image: screenshot]